# Legal to Request Internal Network Information?

Tags: network

Is it legal to access information inside a private network such as a computer's  name, IP address, MAC address, etc? I was told yesterday that a certain program used may be trying to get the name and ID of the PC's in private home networks to verify account security. I was always lead to believe that a reason for internal and external IPs was to hide the network from the outside. I don't really believe they are doing it because it feels like more trouble than the service really would go through. Not entirely sure though. Don't really like the idea of them harvesting information they don't really need when my network is controlling what goes where.

Comment: This is really a question for an attorney.  Much of the answer to this question is going to depend on the jurisdiction which you are located in, as well as any legal agreements which you have signed (including EULAs).

Comment: For questions about legality see [law.se]. *"I was always lead to believe that a reason for internal and external IPs was to hide the network from the outside."* - the "hiding" is done by using [private addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) which are not routable to the internet and thus cannot be accessed directly from the internet. It is not really done by keeping the internal IP secret, in fact it is often easily predictable which IP gets used in the network given that one of the predefined private networks is used.

Answer (score 0):

Are they information security auditors? These will most of the time run a network mapping tool such as nmap to check on the security of the internal network. A general scan by the IT security team is acceptable as long as it does not interfere with normal network operations. This is however for companies. For home networks that's a whole different story, but then the ISP will already have this information. Who is really doing the scan here?

Comment: Not really that kind of thing. Imagine outlook requesting your internal PC names or IPs on your network. That is basically the equivalent. I don't want to mention who it is so it can be dealt with without a lot of fuss. I.E. an external party requesting that information from my private home network.